# passing mySQL full-text search relevance values back to PHP generated form

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I'm using php generated forms to do mySQL full text queries on a database.  Matches are ordered according to weighted relevances and returned to the form. My question is:

Is there any way to pass the relevance values as well back to the form?

I'd like to pass the relevance values to JS so that the client might reorder the match list without re-submitting the form back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're finding this:
http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Comment: thank you, though I'd rather not go back to the server for every client side (javascript) event.  I'd rather just reorder a js array of db matches based on client side re-weightings of the mySQL relevance values.